# is it possible to run Java/Swing applications on Java Embedded environment?

Tags: java, swing, embedded, arm

we need to run windows based Swing applications on an embedded ARM9/11 device; since the whole Java 7 SDK is too heavy for these kind of devices we thought to install Java Embedded that should be design for these use cases. Regretefully, we are not able to find out any reference about Java/Swing on Java Embedded environment in java documentation, neither on NetBeans ones. Does anybody know something on this topic?

Comment: I'd be use embedded Java in Android, sure LayoutManagers are little bit different, but without any un_wanted surpises,

Comment: did you also installed some graphics java libraries in addition to Java Embedded? we have an error trying to launch a small swing windows saying "check headless" and in a forum we found that graphical java libraries should be necessary. besides we still haven't understood if it is necessari to have installed X11/x-server to run them or not. thanks.

Comment: I think that your idea required woodoo maybe dirty tricks, everything depends of Platform and vendors for ARM9/11 device, but this forum have got some Q&A about ARM and Java

Comment: we haven't found anything about Java Embedded, GUI Swing applications and ARM embedded systems anywhere in internet. Even documentation seems to be very poor. If you have any useful link could you share it? thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The Caciocavallo project does this.

Unfortunately the Caciocavallo direct framebuffer code is not ready for end use applications.

They would like help with it.

http://openjdk.java.net/projects/caciocavallo/

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully run Java SE 6 Embedded (headful) on an N900 smartphone, including Swing apps such as JEdit.

It doesn't run particularly fast (startup time obviously much longer than a modern desktop) but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't think that ARM9/11 devices would be strong enough to run even the Embedded Java SE 6/7/8, newer ARM SOCs like the Cortex-A9 and COrtex-A15 are.

I have been able to run several non-trivial Java Swing applications on my Samsung Series 3 ARM Chromebook and they seem to be performing well (this is a dual-Cortex A15 machine (Exynos 5250) with 2GB of RAM).

Squirrel SQL and the Swing app of my company run well on JDK8 ARM Linux hardfloat which has just been released as early access in Aug 2013.